# Usage of Automapper when property names are different

Tags: c#, properties, automapper

We are using AutoMapper from Codeplex and for me the destination object has all the properties ending with 'Field', ie cityField and the source object has just city.

I can use the below code to achieve but all of the properties are just suffixed with 'Field' and there are 20 properties.

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.cityField, opt => opt.MapFrom(origin => origin.City));
```

Is there any other way to ignore 'Field' word when mapping and so that it can map without using .ForMember() 20 times?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try recognizing postfixes:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.RecognizePostfixes("Field");
    cfg.CreateMap<Source, Dest>();
});
```

Recognizing prefixes also works local to profiles, if it's just a set of maps that this applies to.

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll have to implement your own [INamingConvention](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/INamingConvention.cs) to work around this.