# How to specify mapping rule when names of properties differ

Tags: c#, automapper

I am a newbie to the Automapper framework. I have a domain class and a DTO class as follows:

```
public class Employee
{
   public long Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Phone {get;set;}
   public string Fax {get;set;}
   public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
}

public class EmployeeDto
{
   public long Id {get;set;}
   public string FullName {get;set;}
   public DateTime DateOfBirth {get;set;}
}
```

Note: The name of property "**Name**" of `Employee` class is not the same as that of property "**FullName**" of `EmployeeDto` class.

And here's the code to map the `Employee` object to `EmployeeDto`:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>(); // code line (***)
EmployeeDto dto = Mapper.Map<Employee, EmployeeDto>(employee);
```

My question is: If I want to map `Employee` (source class) to `EmployeeDto` (destination class), how can I specify the mapping rule? In other words, how should I do more with code line (***) above?

Answer (score 382, accepted):

Never mind, I myself found a solution:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name));
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify it globally for any class, something like prefix/suffix thing? For example, I have a bunch of classes fro a library that have "Localizations" property each. And I want to map them to classes where corresponding property is called "LocalizedName". Is my only option is to add ForMember to each mapping configuration?

Comment: there is no CreateMap method in Mapper class :(

Comment: @Navid_pdp11 yes there is. You need to have the static class Mapper not an instance

Comment: @JordyvanEijk What version are you using that has a static "CreateMap" method? In 5.1.1.0 there's no such thing

Comment: @MattThomas As long as i can remember the CreateMap is a static method on the Mapper class at the moment i'm using 4.1.1 for a project but i dont know about the newer ones!

Comment: @MattThomas After taking a look at the github of automapper i see that as of version 5.0 CreateMap is obsolete and they say you need to use the MapperConfiguration or Mapper.Initialize.

Comment: I've never used AutoMapper before, I'm reading [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.EF6) and I'm wondering, can Does AutoMapper control the way EF treats my properties? My question is if I can select just the `FullName` property in the above example, or it will be `null`.

Comment: Hi, What if we have many properties we want to map using ForMember. is there any efficient way to do that? rather than copy pasting line for a number of properties.

Comment: is it possible to map a few diff members, but ensure all other identically named members also get mapped?

Comment: @NickAb One option might be to use an [`INamingConvention`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186232/712526).

Comment: how do for multiple fields, and if we have the same field name will it work, or will it still look for the mentioned name only? Or both field there what will happen

Answer (score 19):

Just to roll the comments above into an updated approach using Automapper 8.1+...

```
var mapConfig = new MapperConfiguration(
   cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.FullName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))
);
```

Then you would build the mapper using the mapConfig:

```
var mapper = mapConfig.CreateMapper();
```

Answer (score 8):

We can also specify on Class attributes for mapping

From https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conventions.html#attribute-support

> ### Attribute Support
>
> `AddMemberConfiguration().AddName<SourceToDestinationNameMapperAttributesMember>();`
>   * Currently is always on
>
> Looks for instances of SourceToDestinationMapperAttribute for
>   Properties/Fields and calls user defined isMatch function to find
>   member matches.
>
> MapToAttribute is one of them which will match the property based on
>   name provided.
>
> ```
> public class Foo
> {
>     [MapTo("SourceOfBar")]
>     public int Bar { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Comment: When quoting content from somewhere else verbatim, be sure to use block quote formatting to make it clear to readers that the content is copied.

Comment: Check the new style :) http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Attribute-mapping.html

Comment: Very new to stackoverflow. Sure will follow the rules @TylerH

Comment: That link is now 404

Answer (score 3):

Considering that we have two classes

```
public class LookupDetailsBO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

    }
```

and the other class is

```
public class MaterialBO
    {
        [MapTo(nameof(LookupDetailsBO.ID))]
        public int MaterialId { get; set; }

        [MapTo(nameof(LookupDetailsBO.Description))]
        public string MaterialName { get; set; }

        public int LanguageId { get; set; }
    }
```

In this way you know typically to which property you follow .
and you make sure of the naming convention , so if you have changed the propery name in the source . The **MapTo()** will prompt an error

Answer (score 2):

The new style of Attribute Mapping via Data Annotations:

https://docs.automapper.org/en/v8.1.0/Attribute-mapping.html?highlight=annotation

```
   [AutoMap(typeof(Order))]
   public class OrderDto {
      // This is equivalent to a CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>()
```

For mapping the member

```
   [SourceMember(nameof(Order.OrderTotal))]
   public decimal Total { get; set; }
```

If you want reverse map then you add that property in

```
   [AutoMap(typeof(Order), ReverseMap = true )]
   public class OrderDto {
      // This is equivalent to a CreateMap<Order, OrderDto>().ReverseMap()
```

Answer (score 2):

The above answers are great and hope OP has got his answer. I just want to add how we can map fixed values instead of fields using `UseValue()` method of `IMemberConfigurationExpression` Interface.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Department, opt => opt.UseValue("Development"));
```

This will map "Development" as a Department property value for destination data.