# Forcing a syntax error on automatic ToString() method

Tags: c#, inheritance, tostring, liskov-substitution-principle

By default in c# all classes inherit the `ToString()` method. The problem I'm having is that at work we are using the `automapper` to map some domain objects to the front end. I keep seeing code very similar to the following sudo.

```
string:mapToclass.name <- mapFromClass
```

the problem is that although i'm expecting a string to be mapped from i'm being sent a type with an automatic to string method. The correct code should be similar to the following.

```
string:mapToclass.name <- mapFromClass.name
```

Unfortunately because of the automatic inheritance of the `ToString` method both of these will compile and run. I've though of possibly overriding the string to throw a not implemented exception, but it's not a good design and breaks lsp, plus it still wouldn't catch the error at compile time which would be more ideal.

Any ideas how I could possibly enforce this?

Comment: You need to either override `ToString` yourself on the classes you need to, or find the code that takes the values and change how it works.

Comment: Plus, there is no way to create a `Syntax Error` unless you make your own compiler. You mean a runtime exception.

Comment: You can add code rules that create a sudo-syntax error, we are already doing it here but i'm not sure how i'd implement it in this case.

Comment: How are you enforcing the rules? If the problem is how to write a rule that can catch this behavior, then add some details about it.

Comment: Can you add the actual code that goes behind this? I just attempted to recreate this and Automapper correctly maps mapFromClass.name to mapToClass.name for me. https://gist.github.com/DustinVenegas/6460252

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading this correctly then you can manually specify a mapping in AutoMapper for a case like this.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MapFromClass, MapToClass>().ForMember(dest => dest.name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.name));
```

This will explicitly map from a property on the MapFromClass to the MapToClass. [More information on this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777601/how-to-specify-mapping-rule-when-names-of-properties-differ)

Comment: Yes this is currently how it supposed to work, but this will also compile.

Mapper.CreateMap<MapFromClass, MapToClass>().ForMember(dest => dest.name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));

because everything has a default to string method.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you're saying now. I can't test this currently but you might try Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();. According to the docs at https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration-validation AutoMapper checks to make sure that every single Destination type member has a corresponding type member on the source type.