# Linq select instead of foreach

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

I have two collections

```
var campaigns = new List<Campaigns>();
IEnumerable<CampaignsDb> campaignsFromDB = db.Campaigns
        .Where(c => (c.IsDeleted == false))
        .OrderBy(c => c.ScheduleTime)
        .ToArray();
```

Next I'm filling one collection from another using `foreach()` :

```
foreach (var campaign in campaignsFromDB)
{
    campaigns.Add(new Campaigns { CampaignID = campaign.CampaignID, OwnerID = campaign.CreatedBy, AccountID = campaign.AccountID });
}
```

Can I use `Select()` linq method instead of `foreach` loop ?

Comment: Yes, you can but why didnt you just try?

Comment: Do you know about [List.AddRange(...) method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: FYI - I would recommend using a constructor - or use AutoMapper - https://automapper.org/

Comment: @Dr.Snail And that is easily mapped manually in AutoMapper

Comment: @Dr.Snail here a url to what DavidG said https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14777601/how-to-specify-mapping-rule-when-names-of-properties-differ

Comment: @Dr.Snail I didn't suggest AutoMapper though

Comment: @Dr.Snail - and I (who mentioned AutoMapper) didnt provide an answer - so what upvote?

Comment: @RandRandom then write your automapper thoughts into a answer

Comment: @Dr.Snail no thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need the original empty list to start with (e.g. to add some other campaigns first), you can use:

```
var campaigns = campaignsFromDB
    .Select(c => new Campaigns
           {
               CampaignID = c.CampaignID,
               OwnerID = c.CreatedBy,
               AccountID = c.AccountID
           })
    .ToList();
```

However, that will still have fetched the complete campaign information from the database in order to populate `campaignsFromDB`. That's fine if you need that array for some other reason, but if not, you could make it more efficient by putting the projection into the query:

```
var campaigns = db.Campaigns
    .Where(c => !c.IsDeleted)
    .OrderBy(c => c.ScheduleTime)
    .Select(c => new Campaigns
           {
               CampaignID = c.CampaignID,
               OwnerID = c.CreatedBy,
               AccountID = c.AccountID
           })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @Dr.Snail: The first snippet uses `campaignsFromDB`, which is already filtered. The second snippet uses `db.Campaigns`, including the filtering and ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this:

```
var campaigns = db.Campaigns
    .Where(c => !c.IsDeleted)
    .OrderBy(c => c.ScheduleTime)
    .Select(c => new Campaigns
    {
        CampaignID = c.CampaignID,
        OwnerID = c.CreatedBy, 
        AccountID = c.AccountID
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Note that if the OP needs `campaignsFromDB` for another reason, this will make an unnecessary query to the database. Probably worth mentioning as a single line, at least

Comment: Well we don't even know this is using EF so I'm not going to add that. It probably is of course, but with the info we have...

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just

```
var campaigns = db.Campaigns
        .Where(c => (c.IsDeleted == false))
        .OrderBy(c => c.ScheduleTime)
        .Select(c => new Campaigns { CampaignID = c.CampaignID, OwnerID = c.CreatedBy, AccountID = c.AccountID })
        .ToList();
```

or if you need the source set from the database too

```
var campaignsFromDB = db.Campaigns
        .Where(c => (c.IsDeleted == false))
        .OrderBy(c => c.ScheduleTime)
        .ToArray();

var campaigns = campaignsFromDB
        .Select(c => new Campaigns { CampaignID = c.CampaignID, OwnerID = c.CreatedBy, AccountID = c.AccountID })
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Your contribution is appreciated, but what does it add that the existing answers don't already cover?